# Exponential decay of Fourier coefficients correspond to analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking for a proof of the Payley-Wiener theorem saying that an analytic function on $\mathbb{T}$ (the torus) has exponentially decaying Fourier coefficients. I also found a proof of this fact in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=yaov2qvj5YQC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=analytic%20on%20torus%20exponential%20decay%20Fourier%20coefficients&source=bl&ots=N38P4PFLPC&sig=u4Tm-fo4gdtGFahmhBjL6cq1alA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj42oy64OjPAhWIr1QKHd1tBK4Q6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=analytic%20on%20torus%20exponential%20decay%20Fourier%20coefficients&f=false), but I do not get what they are doing there, i.e. how they apply Cauchy's formula.

If somebody could elaborate or prove this from scratch, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5):

- If $f(t)$ is $2\pi$ periodic and $C^\infty$, with $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)e^{-i n t}dt$ then for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ : $f^{(k)}(t) = \sum_{n= - \infty}^\infty (i n)^k c_n e^{i n t}$ and hence $n^k c_n \to 0$ as $n \to \pm \infty$, so that the coefficients $c_n$  are more than polynomially decreasing.
- Now if $f(t) = g(e^{it})$ where $g(z)$ is analytic on $1-\epsilon < |z| < 1+\epsilon$ then for those $z$ : $\ g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n$ (the same coefficients $c_n$ as before (*)) and hence $c_n (1+\frac{\epsilon}{2})^{|n|} \to 0$ as $n \to \pm \infty$, so that the coefficients $c_n$ are exponentially decreasing.

(*) means that the coefficients of the Fourier series of $h(t)  =g(re^{it})$ are $r^n c_n$, which you can show from the Cauchy integral theorem

Comment: why is there such a function $g$?

Comment: @XinWang in your link : "a function [...] can be extended holomorphically to the complex domain"

Comment: So what I wrote are the 2 main theorems you need to know.

Comment: Now if $f(t)$ is real analytic at every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with a radius of convergence $> \epsilon$, then $g(z) = \sum_n c_n z^n$  can be extended analytically to $1-\epsilon < x < 1+\epsilon$, and the above theorem can be applied to show the Fourier coefficients of $f$ decrease exponentially