# Building Fractional Frequencies From Integer Frequencies

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fractional-calculus, fractional-iteration

Given the ability to build any trigonometric polynomial of integer degrees:

$$T_d(\theta) = \sum_{n=-d}^d c_n e^{in\theta}$$

I wish to construct, or technically approximate:

$$e^{it\theta} \>\>\> \mbox{for $t\in [\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}$}]$$

I'm having trouble finding the best way to do this. When I use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fourier+series+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierSeries%22%2C+%22fourierVariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierSeries%22%2C+%22fourierFunction%22%7D+-%3E%22e%5E%28itx%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierSeries%22%2C+%22fourierLimit%22%7D+-%3E%225%22) to calculate the Fourier Series for $e^{it\theta}$ I get the following:

$$F_N(\theta) = \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{(-1)^n sin(\pi t)}{\pi (t - n)}e^{in\theta}$$

1. I'm not sure how it calculates this since $e^{it\theta}$ wouldn't generally be $2\pi$-periodic.
2. Furthermore, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976830/exponential-decay-of-fourier-coefficients-correspond-to-analytic-functions) it is mentioned that the Fourier coefficients of an analytic function must decay exponentially; however, in this case the coefficients decay linearly even though $e^{it\theta}$ is analytic which really confuses me.

My main question is, what's the best/most efficient way of building an $\epsilon$-approximation of $e^{it\theta}$ using $T_d(\theta)$? I would also want to know the asymptotic complexity of such an approximation in $d$. As in, would I need $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ terms? $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon^2})$ terms? $O(\log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))$ terms?

This is a part of some algorithmic research I'm doing that could potentially have a significant impact. Unfortunately however, I don't have a formal background in complex/Fourier analysis so any insight into achieving this or even directions to look into is greatly appreciated! Also, any insight into (1) or (2) would also be very helpful!

Comment: I don't know the precise statement of the Paley-Wiener theorem being linked to but the linked question says "analytic function on the circle": as you say, $e^{it \theta}$ isn't $2 \pi$-periodic so it does not define such a function. Its $2\pi$-periodization will generally fail to even be continuous.

Comment: Have you tried the Chebyshev polynomial approximation method?

Comment: @Somos I think that would also suffer from the same problem no? (since $e^{in\theta} = T_n(\theta) + iU_n(\theta)sin(\theta)$) Either way, in this case, I have an algorithm that builds the trigonometric polynomial and I want to know whether building these fractional frequencies is a good application for it.

Comment: This is **not** the [Chebyshev approximation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Chebyshev_approximation) as applied to $\,e^{it\theta}\,$ **as a function of $t$**.